# What does "Kann weiter" mean?

Tags: translation

In the film Bella Martha, around the 40 min mark, a waiter comes into the restaurant's kitchen and says to the chefs "Die 6 kann weiter".

What does this mean?

Reverso translates this from German to English literally as "Carry on with table 6", which doesn't mean anything in this context.

Reverso also translates it from German to Italian as "Siete pronti con il 6?", which does make sense, but it's not clear how that translation was arrived at.

Comment: *which doesn't mean anything in this context* - it would help if you could give more context, maybe link the scene (as video or screenplay/script) or describe in more detail, what is happening and why "Carry on with table 6" doesn't mean anything here. Can you please edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a workplace setting. They often has specific idioms as **10-4** or, in this case

> Die Sechs kann weiter.

My guess was the waiter tells the cook to do the final preparation of the next course for table six.

Comment: Soll das "Zehn minus vier" oder "Zehn bis Vier" heißen und wo ist das gebräuchlich?

Comment: *U.S. police movies.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-code

Comment: Heißt das, es ist "Zehn, vier" zu lesen?

Comment: So kenn ich es zumindest.